# MySQL Trigger To Update New Row

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

We are in the process of migrating between 2 systems and need to have 2 fields for one of our database tables that always stay in sync. Here is the table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `example` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `object_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `value` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `object_id` (`object_id`)
);
```

Every time one of the systems inserts a new row we need to have object_id set to id. We can't use 'before insert' since the id column is an auto_increment column so it's value is NULL before insert and due to the limitations of the MySQL 'after insert' on triggers I can't do the following:

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_example 
  AFTER INSERT ON  example 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.object_id = NEW.id;
```

I can't update the code for either system so I need a way to accomplish this on the database side. Both systems are going to be inserting new rows. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a trigger which fires before the insert should do the job

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_example 
  BEFORE INSERT ON  example 
  FOR EACH ROW 
  SET NEW.object_id = NEW.id;
```

EDIT:

As the OP pointed out NEW.id won't work with auto-increment; one *could* use the following trigger (use at own risk):

```
CREATE TRIGGER insert_example 
      BEFORE INSERT ON  example 
      FOR EACH ROW 
      SET NEW.object_id = (
            SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT 
            FROM information_schema.TABLES 
            WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE() 
            AND TABLE_NAME = 'example'
      );
```

But I'd rather re-think this somewhat strange requirement - why do you need the pk value twice in the table?

Comment: You can't use before since NEW.id is generated on insert so before the insert it's value is 0.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you cant use a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger?

I've always seen `AFTER INSERT` triggers as a method to manipulate other tables rather than the table for which the trigger was executed on.

Rule of thumb, manipulate table the trigger is running on = `BEFORE INSERT`, manipulate other tables `AFTER INSERT` :)

Comment: You can't use before since NEW.id is generated on insert so before the insert it's value is 0.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. overlooked the fact it was a auto_increment field, sorry. Think your a bit stuck here then. Is there anyway you could fix the database design and get rid of the redundant data? (as in normalize it a bit)

Comment: Nope. It's unfortunately something we have to live with during the migration between the systems. One system uses the ID field and the other uses the OBJECT_ID field. Both need to be present & synced.

Comment: Well, wonk0 have a potential solution for you. I never dared(or needed to) to actually read directly from the infomation schemas though. If you have the same level of paranoia as me. You might be able introduce a ugly hack (but hey, ugly hacking seems to be going on already :P) and introduce a "hacktable", use AFTER INSERT to write to that, and then have a trigger on "hacktable" that updates 'examble'

Comment: That was my thinking too. Not sure why MySQL doesn't allow this pretty trigger since it can be accomplished with two triggers and a hack table.

Answer (score -1):

I think your trigger will never create in the first place because you can't refer NEW.column_name in an AFTER INSERT trigger.

Try doing this in a BEFORE INSERT trigger (PLEASE IGNORE THIS FIX AS IT WILL NOT WORK):

```
CREATE TRIGGER `insert_example` BEFORE INSERT ON `t`
FOR EACH ROW 
SET NEW.`object_id` = NEW.`id`;
```

Please change the table and column names as per your schema.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can't use before since NEW.id is generated on insert so before the insert it's value is 0.

Comment: That's right @Russell C, I think I mixed up 2 things here. Anyways, thanks for correcting me up